# Eclipse m2e plugin seems to require org.eclipse.jem.util 0.0.0

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I try to install the M2E plugin for Eclipse Juno using Help > Install New Software and the update site, `http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases`.  When I try to install the 'Maven Integration for Eclipse' I get the following message:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.3.1.20130219-1424 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.3.1.20130219-1424)
  Missing requirement: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.3.1.20130219-1424
  (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.3.1.20130219-1424) requires
  'org.eclipse.jem.util 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

How can I avoid this error and install the M2E plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem was caused by my installation directory for Eclipse not being
writable.  It was a fresh unconfigured out of the box install, and I had
installed it under `/opt/eclipse` on Linux.  However, Eclipse expects to write to
`configuration` and `p2` subdirectories of the installation directories unless
configured otherwise, and it won't give any obvious error if these are not
available to write to.

You can avoid this error by ensuring your user can write to the installation
directory of Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for the handy tip! I installed Eclipse to a root-owned folder (would like to share across users), so starting it up as `sudo` and then running the installation worked for me.

Comment: This solved my issue as well. I had moved eclipse into the 'Applications' directory on OSX. Which of course can not be written to by the app itself. My solution was to move eclipse to my documents directory.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue even when running an Eclipse instance with full permission.
What actually solved my problem was to provide the Eclipse update site (i.e. in my case...)

```
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/
```

...in addition to the Maven update site itself:

```
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases
```